# Best workout for obstacle race

Tags: running, training

What do you think is the best workout(s) for obstacle race that you can do on a daily/weekly basis?

There are many obstacle races with different obstacles, but what will be good workouts to be prepared for all?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on the [fitness SE](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Not quite, as it includes different sports, like running which is a big portion of it. The idea how you combine in an efficient way the training.

Comment: For home workouts, I've been really happy with [Insanity](http://www.beachbody.com/product/fitness_programs/insanity.do). These are around 45 minute videos of high intensity cardio circuits with lots of sports training style moves, burpees, football sprints, basketball jumps etc. All is done with your own body weight so no equipment is needed.

Answer (score 3):

The highly varied workouts in the [Crossfit](http://www.crossfit.com) 'program' seem well suited to developing the all round functional strength and fitness required for obstacle races. If the race is very long (20 miles or so) then some additional long distance running might need to be incorporated into your program since Crossfit is more targeted at shorter burst activity with most workouts being under 30 minutes duration.

Answer (score 0):

Incorporate some strength breaks into your runs.

A couple times a week, I will stop every mile of a run to go through a set of body weight strength breaks. Push-ups (mostly regular, but will also do inverted/pike push-ups), One-Leg Squats, Burpees, Pull-Ups (run past a playground and use the playground).